# mysql join three tables to display as group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I must to joing three tables but I'm not so good at this.
I have three tables

```
tournaments

id | name |

teams 

id | name

teams_to_tournament

id | tournament_id | team_id
```

now i want to join this into one query so I can display all tournaments and below teams for that tournaments

```
Tournament name 
tournament team1,tournament team 3,...

Tournament name 2
tournament team1,tournament team 3,...
```

please can you help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `GROUP_CONCAT` function with `GROUP BY tournament.name`.

```
  SELECT tr.name AS tournament, GROUP_CONCAT (tm.name) AS teams
    FROM tournaments tr JOIN teams_to_tournaments tt
         ON tr.tournament_id = tt.tournament_id
         JOIN teams tm ON tm.team_id = tt.team_id
GROUP BY tr.name;
```

Read more about `GROUP_CONCAT` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).